# Simple html dom and mysql insert

Tags: php, html, mysql, simple-html-dom

Hello Guys i am using the code bellow to scrap some content.
I need to insert this into mysql. Also i have to check the title if is the same and if it is to do not insert the post.

My code bellow inserts the first record even if it exists.

```
    foreach($html->find('div.article_item') as $div) {

        $title = $div->find('h2.title a ', 0)->innertext;              
        $thumb = $div->find('p.image_left img ', 0)->src;
        $details = $div->children(3)->plaintext;
        $url = $div->find('p.more a', 0)->href;

        //I need only 3 posts to grab
        for( $i= 0 ; $i <= 3 ; $i++ )
        {    

        $qry="SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posttitle ='$title'";
        $result=mysqli_query($connectiondb, $qry);

        //Check whether the query was successful or not
        if($result) {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        //Post Exists
        }else {

        $posttitle = $title;
        $postthumb = $thumb;
        $postdetails = $details;
        $posturl = $url;

        mysqli_query ($connectiondb, "INSERT INTO posts (posttitle, postthumb, postdetails, posturl) VALUES ('$posttitle', '$postthumb','$postdetails','$posturl')");

    }


    }else {
    (mysqli_error());
    }
    mysqli_close($connectiondb);

    } 


// Clear dom object
$html->clear(); 
unset($html); 
}
```

Comment: so ugly indenting and so many sql injections... not good

Comment: And what is exactly your question?

Comment: Ok at your oppinion is ugly.. Please at least explain why it's ugly and how can i make it safer? I am not a pro, i am trying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `== 1` to `> 0` in this case:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // Post Exists
} else {
```

And since you're using mysqli, why not use prepared statements.

Sidenote: I see that comment, *I only need three posts,*

Comment: Hey Ghost... Hello Life Savior... :-) Can you open a chat in here so we can disqus it?

Comment: @IreneT. so what happened after trying this code? you didn't get any errors? i do not know how open the chat, it just pops out itself

Comment: I cant coz it needs more reputation... Is it possible to explain where excactly to put your code? Try this: http://www.chattory.com/?chat=205786

Comment: I tried your code but it inserts one record.. not 3 even if none of them exists in my database.

Comment: @IreneT. wait? did you really want three insertions per title? three inserts per 1 unique title?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62018/discussion-between-irene-t-and-ghost).